# Fluid Player Does Not Work After Browser Re-Size

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am using 100% in the width and height tags and the player works fine no matter what size the browser is when it is first opened but as soon as I resize the browser none of the controls work any longer and it a video is playing the video quits playing and the screen goes black. Do I have to add something or is this just a bug? Oh yeah, this happens in firefox 10.0.2.

Here is my code:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" id="player2" poster="media/Memphis-Beat_Ring-of-Fire.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="media/Memphis-Beat_Ring-of-Fire.mp4" />   
                </video>
                <script>
                    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
                        success: function(player, node) {
                            //$('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
                        }
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This really annoyed me too. I solved it by creating a function for resizing the player...

```
// For adjusting the player size on the fly
            var adjustVideoSize = function(me, el) {
                var width = $('.a_wrapper_that_is_fluid_width').width();
                var height = $('.a_wrapper_that_is_fluid_width').height();
                // min dimensions for the player
                if (width < 256) width = 256;
                if (height < 110) height = 110;
                // MediaElement methods for resizing
                me.setVideoSize(width, height);
                var player = me.player || el.player;
                player.setPlayerSize(width, height);
                player.setControlsSize();
            };
```

And calling it every time the window was resized.